# Obtaing Maximum **Allowed** Value of PositiveSmallIntegerField Django Field

Tags: django

I have the following `PositiveSmallIntegerField` attached to a Model as follows:

```py
class Proficiency(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Proficiency'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Proficiencies'
        ...

    ...

    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=0, 
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(0), 
            MaxValueValidator(10)
        ]
    )
```

I have to do some complex calculations (*which can't be done within the ORM as far as I can see) on an endpoint which returns an average value:

The calculation turns out to be:

```py
candidate['average'] = (candidate['total'] / count) * maximum_value_of_proficiency_rating_field
```

i.e., maximum_value_of_rating_field is 10.

Inspection of this field, and some digging into object attributes etc has lead me to find 10 dynamically as the following:

```py
proficiency._meta.get_field('rating')._validators[1].limit_value
```

Putting this all together, meaning the above calculation becomes:

```py
candidate['average'] = round((candidate['total'] / count) * int(proficiency._meta.get_field('rating')._validators[1].limit_value))
```

***N.B**. *The above is safeguarded when `count` being 0 or `candidate['total']` being 0 (i.e., for divisible by 0 errors) as well by ensuring that they are both positive integer values.*

However, I was wondering if there was a simpler way to find the maximum value of a `PositiveSmallIntegerField`... i.e., either whatever value passed into the `MaxValueValidator(10)` i.e., "10" or if there is no MaxValueValidator, then 32767.

I was thinking something like maybe a method would return this safely, or maybe an attribute on the field, i.e.,:

`proficiency.rating.get_maximum_value()`

or

`proficiency.rating.max_value`

Does anyone know if there is such a class method or attribute on the field to do this?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but instead of `proficiency._meta.get_field('rating')`, you can avoid the call to the "private method" (not really, since Python doesn't have this notion) by calling it on the class: `Proficiency.rating.field` to get to this field

Comment: @onlyphantom Ahhh, yes, that might be a slight improvement.